# Are the "flipped" 10-adic number equivalent to the real segment $[0;1]$

Tags: infinity, p-adic-number-theory

I just came with an question/idea trying to really feel why real numbers a uncountably infinte. I know Cantor's diagonal argument and I'm quite convinced by it, but here is the idea I had which has to be wrong somewhere, but I can't see where.

Let's write $\overline{n}$ the flipped version of some natural number $n$ (so $\overline{6320} = 0236$), and define the function $f$ such that

$f(n) = 0.\overline{n}$

I have the feeling that every real number between $0$ and $1$ will eventually be described if we let $n$ going through all the natural numbers, but then it would create a mapping between $\mathbb{N}$ and the real segment $[0;1]$, and so $\mathbb{R}$...

I think that a way of putting my question would be : are the "flipped" 10-adic number equivalent to the real segment $[0;1]$ ? And if so, why are the reals uncountable ??

Comment: "I have the feeling that every real number between 0 and 1 will eventually be described if we let  going through all the natural numbers" Where's $1\over 3$?

Comment: $10$-adic numbers can be *infinitely* long. The natural numbers can be *arbitrarily* long, but they can't be infinitely long.

Comment: @BrianTung I think the OP is using "10-adic" to just refer to "base-10," not in its [technical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) (link included for OP). To the OP, indeed the set of 10-adics (or $p$-adics for any $p$, including composite $p$s like $10$) is indeed "exactly as big as" $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: To answer @NoahSchweber, intuitively I would say that $\frac{1}{3}$ would the image of the number ....33333.0 But the question is then : is ....33333.0 a natural number. Brian Tung says "natural numbers can be arbitrarily long, but they can't be infinitely long" and I think that's the core of my misunderstanding ; how can a set contain arbitrarily long numbers without containing infinitely long ones ?

Comment: @MehdiMABED The "number" $\dots 33333.0$ is not a natural number, nor an integer.

Comment: "Arbitrarily long" means that you can specify any number of digits, no matter how large, and find an example of a natural number with that many digits.  "Infinitely long" means that for any number of digits you choose, the number has more digits than that.  Integers may have arbitrarily many digits (that is, you can find integers of any finite length), but not infinitely many digits.

Answer (score -4):

To get a intuitive feeling that the reals are uncountably infinite, you need to understand three things:

(1) The power set of any set is strictly larger than the original set. In a sense, this "intuitive feeling" is basically "all possible combination of things in the set" is kind of a dimension higher than the things in the set.

(2) The set of real numbers is the power set of the set of integers, by definition of how the real number works in decimal representation.

(3) The term "uncountably infinite" is just a fancy way to say "strictly larger than the integer set".

Now p-adic number has nothing to do with countability, it has some technical insights that you can infer from the comment of this thread.

Edit: To answer your original question, by definition of how the series representation of the p-adic number is constructed, the set of base-p p-adic numbers is indeed "uncountably infinite", but that's not what they are useful for.

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: The question really has nothing to do with $10$-adic numbers, and a $p$-adic number is not "just a fancy way of writing the infinite sequence $a_0x^0 + a_1x^1 + a_2x^2 + \dotsb$".

Comment: I addressed the "has nothing to do" in my answer and tried to provide an intuition of why the reals are uncountably infinite. For the infinite sequence part, isn't that how they are defined? I admit I only came across it in the Veritasium video but it seems that their actual usage (at least to solve the particular problem in that video) also involves heavily the sequence definition.

Comment: No.  A $p$-adic number is an element of the Cauchy completion of the rational numbers with respect to the norm induced by the $p$-adic absolute value (this absolute value, denoted by $\|\cdot\|_p$, is defined on the rationals by observing that if $p$ is a prime number, then any rational number can be written as $p^n \frac{a}{b}$ where $n$ is an integer, and $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ are both relatively prime to $p$; if $q = p^n \frac{a}{b}$, then $\|q\|_p = p^{-n}$).  It is true that a $p$-adic number can be represented by a series...

Comment: ...but that series will be of the form $$\sum_{k=-n}^{\infty} a_k p^k, $$ where $n$ is an integer and $a_k \in \{0,1,\dotsc,p-1\}$ for each $k$ (which is different from what you wrote), and the notion of "convergence" here is different from convergence in the reals.

Comment: Alright, I see the "x" I use is causing confusion, also the misuse of term "sequence", will edit it out. The absolute value notation is also introduced in the Veritasium video and the way I see it, is just making more definition on that "short-hand way of writing the series" in order to solve more problem quickly. These definition can also be made directly using the series notation, it's just that the notation becomes longer and harder to read/write

Comment: The way you see it is not really relevant.  A $p$-adic number is a specific kind of object (it can be viewed as the Cauchy completion of the rationals with respect to the $p$-adic absolute value; alternatively, a $p$-adic integer can be seen as an element of the inverse limit of the sequence $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \dotsb$, at which point a $p$-adic *number* is an element of the field of fractions).

Comment: It is possible to *represent* a $p$-adic number by a series (note that such a series needn't start at index 0, and generally *won't*), but this does not mean that a $p$-adic number *is* such a series.

Comment: Okay, I will accept that my understanding of p-adic is not deep enough as the only reference I learnt is the Veritasium video, and hence I will remove that part of my answer. However I still believe the uncountability part is really an intuition that will help the OP to understand why the reals are bigger than the integers, from a constructive intuitive point of view rather than a contradiction point of view (and I believe that part is what the OP is originally looking for).

Comment: For what it is worth, I think that the crash-course on $p$-adic numbers that I wrote at the start of the fourth chapter of my PhD thesis is a reasonable introduction to the topic (if you are willing to do the work to read through it):  https://escholarship.org/uc/item/10p9q9b0#main .